# Making An Image Background Transparent

Tags: gimp, export, transparency, file-format

I followed these two direction [Making the background of an image transparent in Gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent-in-gimp) and [Gimp Tutorial – How to make an image background transparent](http://mbrsolution.com/tutorial/gimp-tutorial-how-to-make-an-image-background-transparent.php)

[image: Three Branch]

You can find the image here on [Bing Images](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=branches&qs=n&form=QBIR&pq=branches&sc=8-8&sp=-1&sk=#view=detail&id=1A02EB9B9B4FE2636CDCB9ED1EB522712596EAEE&selectedIndex=3). The trouble I'm having is it will not export to a .png withn or without changes.  I have Gimp 2.8.10.  Can anyone help explain as to why I can't export this image?

Here is what I get when I try to export:

[image]

Well for this particular image I had to use InkScape to export to a .png and then do my retouches in Gimp.  But, it would be nice to know why this particular image wouldn't work in Gimp. I'll post this on there Forum to see if anyone can come up with an answer.

Thanks!...

Comment: This is a tech support issue. Your operating system is not allowing the image to be saved to the location you've chosen.

Comment: I'm able to export from .jpg to .png to this directory with no problem using other images using Gimp.  As you can see all the .png's in this folder are from exported .jpg's.  Its just this image I'm having a problem with and I'm the Superuser on my Windows 8.1.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem by exporting using InkScape 0.48 and then using Gimp for my retouches.

Answer (score 0):

Should have done this in the first place is updated to the latest version of Gimp 2.8.14!  Apologize for wasting your time!  Was able to successful do everything as expected.  You can removed this posting if you feel it will not help another user, but I'm sure they would do exactly what I just did is upgrade.

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Hi Nasheayahu. What might actually help other people in the future is if you state the exact version you upgraded to. "Latest version" is going to be different in a few years, but this question and answer may very well still remain. By being explicit, you remove the risk of your answer becoming invalidated by a future version.

Comment: So the issue was most likely some meta data (Exif or similar) that was attached to the JPEG file. Exporting from Inkscape might drop that, and whatever bug was causing this - maybe in libexif or libpng - was either fixed in GIMP 2.8.14 or one of that libraries.